# Recursive function calls inside else block

Tags: python-3.x

How does a recursive function call work? Here is the code snippet that I'm trying to understand.

```
def some_func(num):
    if num == 3:
        print (num)
    else:
        num += 1
        some_func(num)
        print('final')

some_func(0)
```

Output:

```
3
final
final
final
```

I thought after it hits the if condition for num == 3, it only executes the print statement inside the if block and exits, but it goes ahead to execute the print('final') statement thrice. Why?

Comment: There's nothing magical about a recursive call; after the call finishes, execution continues with the next line.  And `return` only finishes a particular call, not every call made to the same function.

Comment: It seems the indentation of the code is not accurate.  And it actually is critical to expect the behavior of this script.  Can you fix the indentation?

Comment: @kotaMori -- Fixed indentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the other 3 'finals' are for 0, 1 and 2 respectively. When 3 got printed finally, the function is returned to its parent(2) which then proceeded to print "final" and then returned to its parent(1). It's repeated until it's finally returned to the call when num == 0.